# Interaction between fast charged particles & static electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photon-emission

Can somebody help me understand this section from a paper from U. Fano called "Penetration of Protons, Alpha Particles, and Mesons". $d\sigma_n$ (11) is the cross section for the interaction of a fast moving charged particle with an electron.

$p$ and $p'$ are the initial and final momentum of the charged particle respectively.

$n$ and $0$ correspond to the energy states of the atom carrying the electron with the atom energy states $E_0$ and $E_n$ before and after the interaction respectively.

$Q$ is the kinetic energy of the electron after the interaction. The momentum transfer is considered to be large enough, so that the electron is unbound afterwards.

The equation for $d\sigma_n$ (11) can easily be derived using Fermi's golden rule.

I don't understand the emission-absorption interaction and how this leads to equation (12).

Even though 42 is the answer to everything the citation (42) right before equation 12 doesn't help me either.

Has somebody ever seen something like this and can explain this to me. Or can someone at least show me a source, where I can better understand this & look this up?

Thank you very much in advance!
[image: articles excerpt]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interactions between charged particles and photons can be described by the Hamiltonian $ej_\mu A^\mu$. From quantum field theory view this is of course the interacting vertex, where $j_\mu$ is the particle current. But there is a view from electrodynamics, which could be more pictorial:
the interaction is actually between the electromagnetic field induced by the charged particle current, classically we know
\begin{equation}
\vec{B_j}(\vec{r})=\int\frac{(\vec{r'}-\vec{r})\times\vec{j}}{|r'-r|^3}dV'
\end{equation}
And the energy(Hamiltonian) density of magnetic field is ~$B^2=(B_j+\nabla\times A)^2$, so we have 
\begin{equation}
H_m=\int \frac{1}{2}B^2dV
\end{equation}
Actually the cross term $(\vec{B_j}\cdot\nabla\times A)$ is the interaction we need:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int \vec{B_j}\cdot\nabla\times AdV &=\int\nabla\cdot(\vec{A}\times\vec{B_j})dV-\int\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\times\vec{B_j}dV \\
&=-\int\vec{A}\cdot\nabla_r\times\int\frac{(\vec{r'}-\vec{r})\times\vec{j'}}{|r'-r|^3}dV' \\
&=\int\vec{A}\cdot\int\nabla_{r'}\times\frac{(\vec{r'}-\vec{r})\times\vec{j'}}{|r'-r|^3}dV' \\
&=\int \vec{A}\cdot\vec{j}dV
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Electric potential $\vec{A}$ can be expanded by polarization vector, and considering the coupling $e$, electric charge number $Z$ and exponential factor due to Fourier expansion, the Hamiltonian should be like that. 
Will this satisfy your question?

Answer (score 0):

The process of emission and absorption of virtual photons can be understood by quantum field theory. In quantum electrodynamics the propagator of virtual photon is written as
\begin{equation}
~\frac{ig_{\mu\nu}}{q^2}
\end{equation}
i is the imaginary unit, and $g_\mu\nu$ is the metric. q is four momentum. So the term appears in the denominator is $~q^2=-\vec{k}^2+\omega^2$. The total amplitude of emission absorption process is by calculating the Feynman diagram.
If limited in quantum mechanics frame, the reference 42 gives some explanation but I can't formulate it out fully yet.

Comment: Using the mentioned Fourier integral, it's easy to see why this 1/k^2 appears here, but I don't understand why z*e*c*alpha*A*exp(-ikr_j) describes the interaction i.e. the emission & absorption of a virtual photon. Can you explain, where this comes from? (And thank you for answering in the first place)

Comment: Well, some more explanation about the Hamiltonian zec*alpha*A*exp() term is added into the answer.